# Как получить данные в сервлете из ajax c помощью метода getParametr, без форм и input

Tags: javascript, java, ajax, servlet

Всем доброго вечера. Уже который час мучаюсь.
Использовать только чистый JS.

Задача: отправить через ajax айдишник в сервлет (java). 
Раньше отправлял `xhr.send(string)` после чего вытягивал с помощью такой конструкции, что по мне полный бред, с учетом того что нужно только 1 значение.

```js
BufferedReader json = new BufferedReader(
  new InputStreamReader(request.getInputStream(), "UTF-8"));
String line = null;
String str = new String();
while ((line = json.readLine()) != null) {
  str += line;
}
```

Вот мой запрос в servlet:

```js
var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
function reqReadyStateChange() {
  if (xhr.readyState == 4) {
    var status = xhr.status;
    if (status == 200) {
      var data = xhr.responseText;
      console.log(data);
    }
  }
}

xhr.open("POST", srvUrl, true);
xhr.onreadystatechange = reqReadyStateChange;
xhr.setRequestHeader("Content-Type", "application/json; charset=UTF-8");
xhr.send( "Что сюда отправить?" );
```

В метод send что нужно отправить чтобы передать ID, и в сервлете его получить методом `request.getParametr("myid");`

Очень надеюсь на вашу помощь, решения с помощью jQuery находил, но меня интересует чистый JS.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Можно использовать объект [`FormData`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/FormData/Using_FormData_Objects) для отправки в [`XmlHttpRequest.send()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/XMLHttpRequest/send).

```
var formData = new FormData();
formData.append("myid", myid);
xhr.open("POST", srvUrl);
xhr.onreadystatechange = reqReadyStateChange;
xhr.send(formData);
```

Comment: Сейчас попробую, кто-то уже минусанул вас(

Comment: Все работает, спасибо) единственное нужно не забыть указать xhr.setRequestHeader("Content-Type", "multipart/form-data; charset=UTF-8");

Answer (score 1):

Можно не чего не отправлять в `.send()`, а передать id через url query `?id=1`

```
var sevUrl = 'http://example/path?id=' + id;

xhr.open("POST", srvUrl, true);
xhr.onreadystatechange = reqReadyStateChange;
xhr.send();
```

Comment: да, скорее все через get и придется делать, так как простого способа отправки числа через POST не нашел, либо делать скрытый input